# Parsing Dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm receiving a JSON files that contains a list of files each with a number representing the total number of lines it contains.  The file names can change over time.  Does JSON.NET provide a mechanism to handle this scenario?

In the sample JSON below, I am specifically interested in items under noOfProductsByFile.  The list of files is variable and I would need to consume them through some type of dynamic object.

```
{
  "noOfProductsByFileType" : {
    "rdi_product_stuff" : 41228,
    "rdi_product_junk" : 62519,
    "rdi_product_otherStuff" : 165023,
    "rdi_product_bobsJunk" : 1289
  },
  "startTime" : "20160907050000",
  "endTime" : "20160907052713",
  "timeTaken" : "27 minutes and 13 seconds",
  "noOfProductsBySecurityType" : {
    "AGENCIES" : 41228,
    "ASTBK" : 50991,
    "TSYCURV" : 78
  },
  "noOfProductsByFile" : {
    "rdi_product_stuff_1_of_1.json" : 41228,
    "rdi_product_junk_1_of_2.json" : 60219,
    "rdi_product_junk_2_of_2.json" : 2300,
    "rdi_product_myStuff_1_of_2.json" : 147690,
    "rdi_product_myStuff_2_of_2.json" : 17333,
    "rdi_product_test_1_of_1.json" : 1289
  },
  "noOfProducts" : 1925914
}
```

Comment: yes it does, as you parse the json text and not the file

Answer (score 10):

There are a few options to use. Here's one using the ExpandObject

```
dynamic dynData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

You can then reference the fields as you would a normal object:

```
dynData.noOfProductsByFileType.rdi_product_stuff
```

If you need to handle fields that may or may not be present, ExpandoObjects can be cast to a IDictionary and refer to fields as follows:

```
((IDictionary<string,object>)dynData)["noOfProductsByFileType"]
```

Assign to a IDictionary type and iterate through properties or test if a property exists

```
var dictData = (IDictionary<string,object>)dynData;
var noOfProductsByFileTypeDict = (IDictionary<string,object>)dynData.noOfProductsByFileType; // objects within objects
```

Test For Property

```
dictData.containsKey("testprop"); // test for a property - testprop
```

or Iterate

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in noOfProductsByFileTypeDict) ... //iterate
```

Comment: Nice answer! OP will probably want to iterate rather than hardcoding the names of these files. It's a dynamic list. But I see that, using the `ExpandoObject`, you can safely `foreach` over `dynData.noOfProductsByFile` and then read off the `.Key` and `.Value` properties. You may want to amend your answer.

Comment: FWIW: You don't really _need_ to cast to a dictionary to iterate. you can just do `foreach (var property in dynData.noOfProductsByFile)` and then `string file = property.Key;` and `long noOfProducts = property.Value;`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are a number of ways to handle this. One simple way is to use a `JObject`.

```
var jsonString = "...";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (JProperty e in jObject["noOfProductsByFile"])
{
    var file = e.Name;
    var noOfProducts = e.Value;
    Debug.WriteLine(file);
    Debug.WriteLine(noOfProducts);
}
```

Comment: You can also use JObject.Parse( jsonstring ) instead of the JsonConvert

Comment: Good catch. Updated.